# Floodfill com primefaces. Pegar coordenada de clique em p:graphicImage

Tags: java, jsf, imagem, primefaces, aplicação-web

Eu quero fazer um aplicativo de pintura de imagens utilizando java. Como é pra ambiente web eu escolhi o primefaces como framework pela vasta documentação que existe sobre ele.

Entretanto não encontrei nenhum componente que fosse util nesse tipo de aplicação.

vendo o showcase do primefaces vi que existe um componente p:graphicImage que poderia resolver aquilo que preciso. Mas eu não faço ideia de como descobrir a coordenada do clique em um componente desse tipo. Se eu conseguisse essa informação poderia processar a imagem e exibir ela pintada para o usuário.

Alguém ja fez algum aplicativo desse tipo?

Obrigado.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O grande [@BalusC](https://stackoverflow.com/users/157882/balusc) [postou uma solução](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13162082/1683070) para isso, porém não específica ao PrimeFaces. Irei transcrever a parte relevante abaixo...

---

A melhor maneira de fazer isso é colocar campos ocultos com as respectivas coordenadas, vinculados a propriedades do seu *managed bean* e atualizar esses valores via Javascript/jQuery.

Exemplo:

```html
<h:form>
    <h:graphicImage id="image" name="image1.png">
        <f:ajax event="click" execute="x y" listener="#{bean.listener}" />
    </h:graphicImage>
    <h:inputHidden id="x" value="#{bean.x}" />
    <h:inputHidden id="y" value="#{bean.y}" />
</h:form>

<h:outputScript>
    jQuery("img[id$=':image']").on("mousedown", function(event) {
        var $form = jQuery(this).closest("form");
        $form.find("input[id$=':x']").val(event.pageX);
        $form.find("input[id$=':y']").val(event.pageY);
    });
</h:outputScript>
```

*Nota: você precisa do jQuery pelo menos na versão 1.7 para usar o `jQuery.on()`. Em versões anteriores, use `jQuery.bind()`.*

E o *Managed Bean* seria assim:

```java
@ManagedBean
@RequestScoped
public class Bean {

    private Integer x;
    private Integer y;

    public void listener() {
        System.out.println(x + ", " + y);
    }

    // ...
}
```

---

No entanto, em seu lugar eu não usaria componentes JSF para essa tarefa.

Crie um Web Service REST ou um simples Servlet que receba os devidos parâmetros e retorne a imagem.

Então você pode colocar uma imagem normal do HTML (`<img/>`), usar o jQuery para capturar o clique e então, a cada evento, ir alterando a URL da tag de imagem, pois o Servlet será chamado e retornará a imagem atualizada.